# Express.js / while-else loop redirection problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.post('/process', function(request, response){  
  var i = 0;
    while(i < data.length){
        if(data[i].condition1 == condition1 && data[i].condition2 == condition2){
            response.redirect('/first_page');
          }
          i++;
      }
      response.redirect('/second_page');
}
```

I tried to make if condition 1 and condition 2 are true, redirect to first page.
And if it is false, redirect to second page.
But it keeps occurring an error. Here's log.

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: while-else? anyway, your code will almost certainly try to send more than one  redirect - which is probably causing the issue

Comment: @JaromandaX then how can i redirect to two different pages as two conditions in one direct?

Comment: @JaromandaX i hope if false, users redirect to second page

Comment: You can add a `return` statement after the redirect in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to redirect to "first_page" if ANY item in Array data matches the condition or "second_page" if none match the condition,

Simplest change to your code is

```
app.post('/process', function(request, response) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i].condition1 == condition1 && data[i].condition2 == condition2) {
      response.redirect('/first_page');
      return; // done, no need to check any more of data
    }
    i++;
  }
  response.redirect('/second_page');
});
```

However, using `Array#some` with if/else will work

```
app.post('/process', function(request, response) {
  if (data.some(item => item.condition1 == condition1 && item.condition2 == condition2)) {
    response.redirect('/first_page');
  } else {
    response.redirect('/second_page');
  }
});
```

`data.some` will return true if any item in data matches the condition otherwise will return false

Personally, I prefer the Array.some code as it is tidier and more obvious as to what is happening